# How to implement a vertically sliding fragment / panel like Google music in an Android app?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sliding

I'm trying to create a sliding panel that slides to collapse / expand vertically and not horizontally.

I've tried [Umano's](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) Library but it's kind of buggy for me, because I'm using Fragments, and not Activities.

Any way to implement this with fragments?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the bugs that you are experience with the SlidingUpPanel, I'm happy to look into them

Comment: Did you found anything? useful instead of Umano's library..... I am wondering that only one library available for the same (can't use bottom sheet persistent and modal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if any one wants to know, 
i Did used [Umano's Library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)
bugs were fixed using the git manager.
Works great.

Comment: Agreed.  Their component works quite well and is only one class.

Comment: Agree - good library.  Can anyone comment how to make the SlidingUpPanel vertically scrollable, if there is too much content to display, like ScrollView.. ?

Comment: i tried their library. But my xml turns up blank, anybody else having the same problem?

Comment: I want to attach a <fragment ...></fragment> inside of SlidingUpPanel, but there is an error which says "Expression fragment is not allowed here."

Comment: Umano's library has not been mainained and is full of bugs now!  Any alternatives out there?

Comment: yes have tried Umano's library but after when you load fragment inside the sliding panel have faced performance issues

Answer (score 4):

that is called a [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) (which is deprecated as of API level 17 BTW) so I would not recommend using it unless you fork it from the SDK as your own

SlidingDrawer Examples:

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/01/slidingdrawer-in-android-a-simple-example/

http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.com/2013/05/slidingdrawer-in-android-example.html

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-damn-that-sliding-drawer/

[SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) does this `SlidingPaneLayout provides a horizontal, multi-pane layout for use at the top level of a UI. A left (or first) pane is treated as a content list or browser, subordinate to a primary detail view for displaying content.`

you can view the sliding pane in the new hangouts app

Comment: Nope @tyczj , thats called [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) only horizontal, and that's availible since API level 13.

if Goggle just added that to their Music App, u can be sure that's it's ok to use it

Comment: no it is not did you even click my link? The sliding drawer slides up from the bottom just like you want. Quote from the docs `SlidingDrawer hides content out of the screen and allows the user to drag a handle to bring the content on screen. SlidingDrawer can be used VERTICALLY OR HORIZONTALLY.`

Comment: I listed some examples of the sliding drawer

Comment: Then I do not understand what you want, you said you wanted something that open vertically like the music app...and thats what this does??

Comment: take a look at the music app...
unlike the sliding drawer, his dragging handle has content, you can see the current time updates etc. which is part of a whole view.
The sliding drawer in the other hand , has a static handle...

Comment: yes so you have to customize it...there is not drag and drop item that does what you want if that is the answer you are looking for. what you see in the music app is based on the slidingdrawer

Comment: @tyczj answer is correct. SlidingDrawer is exactly what you are looking for. You just need add some code for use with Fragments. Check source code here https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java

Comment: How can i set the height of minimized SlidingUpPanel?I want my panel should display four images of gridview even when in minimized state.User can slide it to top to see complete gridview.How can i increase the height of minimized sludinguppanel so that it can show more content?